# OSGi Threading Model

Tags: osgi

I have searched the Internet but failed to find a satisfactory answer. What is the threading model present in an OSGi container? Does it simply spawn a new thread to each registered bundle e.g.? Any reference regarding the threading model would be great.

Answer (score 10):

You have not found anything because there is no such thing as an "OSGi threading model". Bundles simply exist and don't "have threads" unless they start them.

Comment: I am still confused. You mean to say that unless the bundles fork threads there is just a single threaded execution? In this scenario how does multitasking works? For example one bundle may be doing a computation while another bundle is serving a network request. How does scenario like this is handled in the framework? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Yes, bundles are free to create threads as they need them. If a bundle is doing a long-running computation or serving a network request, those things typically happen in threads that are created by the bundle. Please read the concurrency chapter of my (free, but unfinished) book: http://njbartlett.name/osgibook.html

Comment: Wow, Neil - that is an excellent book! Oh, and I just saw you are talking about DS too - can't wait to get there. Hope you will continue writing it, and I would buy a hardcopy!

Answer (score 4):

The OSGi framework follows a synchronous model, ie. everything happens in a strict order. Bundles are not executed in threads (but they have their own classloader instances). There are some exceptions, though. For example, when an event is raised via the *postEvent* method, the delivery of the event is done asynchronously, usually implemented in many framework implementations as a thread.

Answer (score 4):

When you start a bundle, code in activator is executed in one thread, similar to the 'main' thread. When the main thread completes its execution, bundle is changed from the 'Starting' state to 'Active' state. So it is better to execute time consuming code in another thread and starting another thread from the main thread.

When service method gets called from service consumer. At that time, the code written in the service method get executed in service consumer's thread.

I didn't find any difference between static variables and local variable in the service method.

Answer (score 0):

Besides some special cases (Events/Listeners) the application threads are neighter managed nor restricted. You can use threading freely. You do need to be aware that some operations in the bundle lifecylce must be (therefore) thread safe and you need to be very carefull to tear down threads cleanly. You also need to be carefull not to block OSGi operations needlessly long.